# html2ps + ImageMagick + libwww-perl not working together

Tags: html, image, imagemagick, libwww-perl, html2ps

**Summary:**

I am using html2ps to convert an html document with inline images. (I have both ImageMagick and libwww-perl installed.) If the images are local, this works fine; however, when the images are given through a URL, I just see [IMAGE] instead of my image.

I also tried using wget instead of libwww-perl, with the exact same result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Code:**

I always compile with

```
html2ps -d example.html > output.ps
```

I have the same image file in two places: ./local.png and http://www.example.com/remote.png.

The following html inserts the image into the ps document:

```
<img src='local.png' />
```

but this line just inserts the word [IMAGE]:

```
<img src='http://www.example.com/remote.png' />
```

The output I'm getting is

```
html2ps version 1.0 beta7
Reading example.html
Image: local.png
convert /var/tmp/aaaVtaOy5 /var/tmp/aaaVtaOy5.ppm
Size: 8*10
Image: http://www.example.com/remote.png
Retrieving http://www.example.com/remote.png
```

and a local copy of the image is created.

Answer (score 0):

html2ps requires that remote documents include their HTTP headers. I got it to work by using wget instead of libwww-perl:

```
geturl: "wget --quiet -O - --save-headers";
libwww-perl: 0;
```

It seems that this is still probably not the best solution.